# Inserting line break or tab with preg_replace

Tags: php, html, json, regex

I am making a webpage in which I have to insert in a JSON variable ($grav which contains all the raw data from JSON) a line break or a tab in 3 given situations. After that I force the download of the data as a xls file. Everything is working except the "preg_replace" part. It finds the delimiter, but instead of inserting a "\n" or "\t" it only inserts a white space, according to the xls file downloaded (the data is all in one cell instead of in multiple columns and lines (that is why I need line breaks and tabs).

```
$grav='"title":[{"field1":,"field3":,{"field4"}';
        
        $grav = preg_replace("/\},\{/",  "},\n{",  $grav);
        $grav = preg_replace("/\[\{/",  "\n[{",   $grav);
        $grav = preg_replace("/,\"/",  ",\"\t",  $grav);

        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="data_ '. date("Ymd") . '_' . $id . '.xls"');
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
        header("Content-Type: application/download");
        
        echo $grav;
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: you could go for loop and br the line . why  you trying line this ?

Comment: @VigneswaranS Simply for efficiency. I had loops replacing each occurence and it took too long to do it.

Comment: @stribizhev I called preg_replace correctly i think...the 1st argument is "/\},\{/" the 2nd argument is ""},\n{" and the last is $grav, wich is the string. It does find the occurences of the delimiter (1st argument), but it inserts a white space instead of a line break

Comment: Sometimes tabs don't line up. As for newlines, you should insert a `\r\n` unless you know php will do the translation of newline to CRLF. Most windows files expect a CRLF line break.

Comment: This `preg_replace("/,\"/",  ",\t\"",  $grav);` is probably a better placement for the tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are trying to break a json code into 3 line?. any how i will give a idea to solve this problem using array . try to convert using json. it may helps you

```
<?php 
$fruit = array('a' => 'apple', 'b' => 'banana', 'c' => 'cranberry');// i used associate array which is similar to json data
reset($fruit);
while (list($key, $val) = each($fruit)) {
$grav .= $key."=>". $val."<br>";// brakes the line into 3 
}
  header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="data_ '. date("Ymd") . '_' . $id . '.xls"');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Type: application/download");

echo $grav;
?>
```

Comment: The <br> worked on line breaks.

$grav = preg_replace("/\},\{/","<br>",$grav);
$grav = preg_replace("/\[\{/","<br>",$grav);

This way it separates the lines. 

I still can't correctly insert tabs.... when it finds the delimiter ',"'

Comment: @TiagoFerreira : can you post what $grav contains?

Comment: I managed to find a way to encode the tab character on html: using &#9; i can divide the data into columns thank you for the help